# What is the sum of all 3-digit numbers which are multiples of 14 but are NOT multiples of 21?

Tags: sequences-and-series

And what is the quickest way to solve this with a calculator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between 100 to 1000 are 900 numbers. 900/14 =~ 64 so there will be 64 multiples of 14.  The go from 112 = 8*14 to 71*14 = 994.  The sum of these numbers are 14(8 + ..... + 71).  The sum 8 + .... + 71 = 79*64/2 =  2528.  So the sum of all 3 digit multiples of 14 is 14*2528 = 35392.

Now we must subtract those that are multiples of 21.  Well we only have even multiples of 21 so these are the multiples of 42.  900/42 =~ 21 of theses.  From 42*3 = 126 to 432*23 = 966.  The sum of these are 42(3 + .... + 23) = 42(26*21/2) = 11466.

So the sum is 35,392 - 11,466 = 23,926.

Comment: no this is actually what the question was asking! it was a higher level question in my IB math textbook and you got the correct answer. my friend and i took 2 hours each to solve this question and it was traumatic! thank you for solving this and confirming our answer was correct because we truly weren't sure. <3

Answer (score 0):

Zero.

If you have all the 3-digit positive integers with such conditions and all the 3-digit negative integers with such conditions and then add them all up, you will get zero.

Comment: @fleablood ?!??

Comment: that's BEAUTIFUL, good sir. nowhere in the question was it specified that the numbers had to be positive integers. i am stupefied by your intelligence! i commend you good sir

Comment: Ah, I thought it was asking for the sum of the digits.  Like a rule of 9, and of course there is no rule of 14.

Comment: @Hanalei thanks. Upvote and accept myb? :P

Comment: @Hanalei You phrased your question wrong then?

Comment: @BCLC actually i just copied it straight out of the book :L

Answer (score 0):

Presumably "number" here is interpreted as "nonnegative integer".

Hint: take the sum of those numbers divisible by $14$ and subtract the sum of those numbers divisible by both $14$ and $21$ (and thus by the least common multiple of $14$ and $21$).  Use the fact that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^b i = \dfrac{b(b+1)}{2}$$